# Computing $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}H_n^{(2)}}{(2n+1)^4}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, closed-form, alternative-proof, harmonic-numbers

I managed to find

> $$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}H_n^{(2)}}{(2n+1)^4}=20\beta(6)+\frac12\zeta(2)\beta(4)-\frac{7\pi^3}{32}\zeta(3)-\frac{31\pi}{8}\zeta(5)$$

where $\beta(a)$ is [the Dirichlet Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function?fbclid=IwAR2JKUjyn8sG4wMdUfeT3JyJLpw7C-aanbnwRYbIZ0k9QYwA3Hz1_0OsQhU).

and would like to see different approaches.

---

**Here is my work**

Following the same approach [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3365150)

\begin{align}
6S&=6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}H_n^{(2)}}{(2n+1)^4}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}H_n^{(2)}\int_0^1-x^{2n}\ln^3x\ dx\\
&=\int_0^1\ln^3x\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-x^2)^nH_n^{(2)}\ dx\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\operatorname{Li}_2(-x^2)}{1+x^2}\ dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^3x\operatorname{Li}_2(-x^2)}{1+x^2}\ dx-\underbrace{\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln^3x\operatorname{Li}_2(-x^2)}{1+x^2}\ dx}_{x\mapsto 1/x}\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^3x\operatorname{Li}_2(-x^2)}{1+x^2}\ dx+\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\operatorname{Li}_2(-1/x^2)}{1+x^2}\ dx\\
&\left\{\small{\text{add the integral} \int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\operatorname{Li}_2(-x^2)}{1+x^2}\ dx=6S\text{ to both sides}}\right\}\\
12S&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^3x\operatorname{Li}_2(-x^2)}{1+x^2}\ dx+\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x[\color{red}{\operatorname{Li}_2(-x^2)+\operatorname{Li}_2(-1/x^2)}]}{1+x^2}\ dx\\
S&=\frac1{12}\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^3x\operatorname{Li}_2(-x^2)}{1+x^2}\ dx+\frac1{12}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x[\color{red}{-2\ln^2x-\zeta(2)}]}{1+x^2}\ dx\\
&=\frac1{12}\underbrace{\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^3x\operatorname{Li}_2(-x^2)}{1+x^2}\ dx}_{I}-\frac16\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^5x}{1+x^2}\ dx}_{-120\beta(6)}-\frac{\zeta(2)}{12}\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x}{1+x^2}\ dx}_{-6\beta(4)}\\
&=\frac1{12}I+20\beta(6)+\frac12\zeta(2)\beta(4)\tag1
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^3x\operatorname{Li}_2(-x^2)}{1+x^2}\ dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^3x}{1+x^2}\left(\int_0^1\frac{x^2\ln y}{1+yx^2}\ dy\right)\ dx\\
&=\int_0^1\ln y\left(\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2\ln^3x}{(1+x^2)(1+yx^2)}\ dx\right)\ dy\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln y}{1-y}\left(\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^3x}{1+yx^2}\ dx-\underbrace{\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^3x}{1+x^2}\ dx}_{0}\right)\ dy\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln y}{1-y}\left(-\frac{\pi^3}{16}.\frac{\ln y}{\sqrt{y}}-\frac{\pi}{16}.\frac{\ln^3y}{\sqrt{y}}\right)\ dy,\quad \sqrt{y}=x\\
&=-\frac32\pi^3\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x}{1-x^2}\ dx}_{\frac74\zeta(3)}-2\pi\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4x}{1-x^2}\ dx}_{\frac{93}{4}\zeta(5)}\\
&=-\frac{21}{8}\pi^3\zeta(3)-\frac{93}{2}\pi\zeta(5)\tag2
\end{align}

Plug $(2)$ and $(1)$ we get

> $$S=20\beta(6)+\frac12\zeta(2)\beta(4)-\frac{7}{32}\pi^3\zeta(3)-\frac{31}{8}\pi\zeta(5)$$

---

Thank to @Zacky for spotting couple mistakes in my solution

Comment: Please put the edit note at the top and/or post the solution as an answer. I read through the entire post before finding out that the problem had already been solved.

Comment: @joriki I edited the whole problem now :)